# libstdc++6 stops apt-get from working

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gcc, shared-library

I tried to install the latest version libstdc++6 through the deb file from Ubuntu however now whenever i try to install a package it shows me an error.

```
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
```

I tried to run apt --fix-broken install but an error also showed up. (The error was much bigger and I couldn't get the whole error message.

```
Done
 failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Same for `apt-get -f install`.

How can I fix this?

(I'm on the latest version of KDE Neon based on Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by reverting to the appropriate version of `libstdc++6` for your distribution:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6=8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
```

`libstdc++6` is a system library and somewhat difficult to upgrade.